# Vuejs: How to properly pass props to component data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm playing with Vue 2.0, but there is something unclear..
how can i pass the props to the internal data of a component?
Looking at the documentation it seems that i have done right.

**HTML**

```
<lista-servizi :servizi="modello"></lista-servizi>
```

the "modello" is a data already defined.

**THE VUE COMPONENT**

```
Vue.component('lista-servizi', {
 template:
 '<span class="blu">{{listaServizi.lineaGialla.descrizione}}</span>',
    props: ['servizi'],
    data: function(){
    return{
       listaServizi : this.servizi
    }
```

basically i try to give to data listaServizi the same value as props servizi,
but in the console i have the following message:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'descrizione' of undefined"

found in

---> <ListaServizi>
       <Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should used `computed` instead.

```
Vue.component('lista-servizi', {
  //...
  computed: {
    listaServizi() {
      return this.servizi
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: seems legit! but now i have another problem... in the console i have this

Vue warn]: Property or method "listaServizi" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

may be somthing r

Comment: If you used `computed` exactly like I wrote (and removed `listaServizi` from `data`), this shouldn't be a problem. Like in [this pen](https://codepen.io/luord/pen/pwxZWp)

Comment: yes, my error! it work on rendering in the browser, but in the console i have always the same message...
Should it be a browser problem?

Comment: This is odd, could you edit the question to write how the code in your component looks now? That warning shouldn't appear.

Comment: no, i can'tedit my own question, but i have this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/noupLq78/

Comment: You might be referencing `listaServizi` from somewhere else, not in the component. It's the only thing I can think of right now.

Comment: Maybe i have understand the problem...
i declare the 'modello' in the main.js file using an self-invoked function that do an ajax call, and i'm accessing to it like that

 created:function(){
  this.getModuleData();
 }  

but the main.js file in the HTML il linked after the 'components.js' file, so when it try to get the props object it don't properly read it.

I must figure out how to pass properly

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a problem with ***modello***.
By defining the ***modello***, your code works fine. Below is an example based on your code that works:

```
<div id="app-1">
<lista-servizi :servizi="modello"></lista-servizi>
</div>



Vue.component('lista-servizi', {
  template: '<span class="blu">{{listaServizi.lineaGialla.descrizione}}</span>',
  props: ['servizi'],
  data: function(){
    return{
     listaServizi : this.servizi
    }
  }
})

var app1 = new Vue({
 el: '#app-1',
 data: {
 modello: { 
  lineaGialla : {
    descrizione : " This is a description"
    }
  }
}
})
```

Here is a link to a working bin
https://jsbin.com/qoloqoz/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i'm sure that "modello" is working fine, if i declaring it outside of component, it works